# Should I use destructor or IDisposable in Console application

Tags: c#

Basically I open a database connection when the application starts and it should remain open till the lifetime of the application.

I am using console application for this background job:

```
class Program
    {
        #region '----- Method(s) -----'
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        ~Program()
        {

        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Should I close database connection in my destructor or should I implement IDisposable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IDisposable`.

The best way to do so is to instantiate it within a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Yes but I need the database connection across methods. So using won't work. I need it as an instance variable.

Comment: @Jaggu - You can pass the connection to different methods. Not sure using an instance variable is a good idea when using connections.

Comment: will framework call my dispose method? If I close connection in dispose because it needs to be called explicitly.

Comment: @Jaggu - The connection classes get closed when they are disposed. If you implement `IDisposable` yourself, call `Dispose` on the connections.

Comment: Will this work if the user presses ctrl+c or clicks the close button on the window?

Comment: @TimothyGonzalez - I don't follow. If the program has exited, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Oded I would expect for dispose to be called.

Comment: @Timothy - it would,  at the end of the block. This isn't  c++ and IDisposable is not a finalizer.  Though, when the program closes, all handles it holds should be freed. But that's more of an OS mechanism at that point.

Comment: I don't see a "using" or "try/finally" (a using is just a fancy try/finally right?) work as expected on Windows 10 after pressing ctrl+c in the console or the window close buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Hm..If you not creating an instance of program class then It need no finalizer because finalizers are called only for instance of objects. You need no nor Finalizer, nor IDisposable. You must to do so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    db.Dispose();//In the end of console app executing code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Believe me, you dont want to do that, best practices say to use the connection only when needed and close it as soon as possible.  If what you need is a transaction then you can use a Sql Transaction and put methods inside the using of sql Transaction

```
using(SqlConnection sqlconn= new ())
   using(SqlTransaction sqltrann = new ())
{
  {    
     method1
     method 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a implementation of dispose pattern here which is advisable. Otherwise, make sure you are inheriting your actual type from `CriticalFinalizerObject` in order to enforce CLR to place your type instance in finalization queue irrespective of runtime conditions.

```
class Program:CriticalFinalizerObject
 {
        #region '----- Method(s) -----'
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        ~Program()
        {

        }
        #endregion
}
```